# How to toggle between UITextView's inputviews

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextview, uikeyboard

I am getting problem in making my application compatible with iphone 4.0

My problem is like this.

When i click on a UITextview a custom keyboard is showing

```
UIView *test=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 160, 320, 215)];
        UIExtendedKeyBoard *objKeyBoard =[[UIExtendedKeyBoard alloc] initWithFrame:[test bounds]];
        objKeyBoard.tag =1001;
        [test addSubview:objKeyBoard];
        [objKeyBoard release];
        [vTxtPoem setInputView:test];
        [test release];
```

but when i click on particular button i need to toggle between default key board and my custom key board....i am using the following code to do this

```
[vTxtPoem setInputView:nil];
```

but it is not working ...even it is not showing default keyboard..it is still remain same custom keyboard. the control also coming to this line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first guess would be something like this:

```
[vTxtPoem resignFirstResponder];
[vTxtPoem setInputView:nil];
[vTxtPoem becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Very Thanks it's working fine....:) i dont have reputation other wise i will give 100 points...

Answer (score 3):

A better way might be

```
[vTxtPoem setInputView:nil];
[vTxtPoem reloadInputViews];
```

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/reloadInputViews for details!

Comment: This was the perfect answer. The marked solution actually dismisses the keyboard with animation and then it reappears with animation. Your solution toggled them perfectly. Thanks!!!